# deriving Generic doesn't work even though DeriveGeneric is on

Tags: haskell, generics, haskell-stack

I'm trying to follow the tutorial for the Beam Haskell library: https://tathougies.github.io/beam/tutorials/tutorial1/

```
module Lib
    ( someFunc
    ) where

{-# LANGUAGE
    DeriveGeneric
  , GADTs
  , OverloadedStrings
  , FlexibleContexts
  , FlexibleInstances
  , TypeFamilies
  , TypeApplications
 #-}

import Database.Beam
import Database.Beam.Postgres
import GHC.Generics

import Data.Text (Text)

data UserT f
    = User
    { _userEmail     :: Columnar f Text
    , _userFirstName :: Columnar f Text
    , _userLastName  :: Columnar f Text
    , _userPassword  :: Columnar f Text }
    deriving Generic

someFunc :: IO ()
someFunc = putStrLn "someFunc"
```

This results in the following error:

```
    • Can't make a derived instance of ‘Generic (UserT f)’:
        You need DeriveGeneric to derive an instance for this class
    • In the data declaration for ‘UserT’
   |
27 |     deriving Generic
   |              ^^^^^^^
```

Note that the DeriveGeneric language pragma is present.

What am I missing here?

Build environment:

- stack lts-11.9
- Linux

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `{-# LANGUAGE #-}` declaration needs to go at the very top of the file, before the `module` declaration.

Comment: It should also be noted that GHC doesn't warn about this (although it could) because pragma syntax (`{-# ... #-}`) is a subset of Haskell multi-line comment syntax (`{- ... -}`); presumably, the language pragma parser is disabled after `module` and it is read as a comment.

Comment: @user2407038 although other pragmas like INLINE are still parsed with the same syntax